# Is there any relationship between concurrent neural network and directed probabilistic graphical model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I have some understanding of both models (concurrent neural network and directed probabilistic graphical model). Both of them can be used to model sequential data. But is there any connections between them?